# Iframe displaying pdf from download link

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, hyperlink

I'm programming a html webpage and i need to show in an iframe a pdf that comes from a download link , how i can jump the download link and show the pdf in the  without download the file?.

Sorry if i wrong explained , in short words i need to show in web with iframe the content of a PDF who only link with him is a force download link , i tested your solutions people but it doesn't work for my objectives, any idea ?

Thank you for read me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to load the source, and it will not be visible in `iframe url` in page source code. For example with `jQuery:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('iframe').attr('src','http://www.yourwebsite.com/pdf');
});
</script>

<body>
<iframe src="" />
</body>
```

### [Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/65ytY/64/)

You can combine it with $.post to get the value serverside:

```
$.post('get-iframe-src.php', function(data) {
  $('iframe').attr('src',data);
});
```

You can even load iframe itself to some element like:

```
$.post('get-iframe.php', function(data) {
  $('#element_id').html(data);
});
```

Comment: are you saying you can't access the pdf source in the source code? because you can...

Answer (score 0):

Using an `iframe` to show a PDF will not work in all browsers because some will attempt to download the actual file.

You should have a look a [PDFObjects.](http://pdfobject.com/markup/index.php)

This is how you would use it:

```
 <object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
  you can <a href="myfile.pdf">click here to
  download the PDF file.</a></p>


</object>
```

You can put the URL of the file into the **data** attribute.